# Tablayout with viewpager recyclerview swipe delete

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have implemented Tablayout using viewpager inside recyclerview. and also integrated swipe delete using ItemTouchHelper in recyclerview.

Now i am facing one issue, Can't able to access viewpager moving. When i am trying to change the page its affecting swipe delete function.

Anyone help me out.

Thanks and Regards,
Gowtham.R

Comment: In my opinion, its not good practice to add swipe action to the list items inside view pager. You could add a context menu on long press of the list item instead.

Comment: you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978462/swiperefreshlayout-viewpager-limit-horizontal-scroll-only

Answer (score 1):

why delete swipe ?! 
you can use this under methods for disable swipe in viewPager :
it worked for me.

```
view_pager.setOnTouchListener { _, _ -> true }
```

and

```
view_pager.beginFakeDrag()
```

and now you can change the page with Above Tabs in TabLayout.