# Disable vertical swipe (SwipeRefreshLayout) when swiping in a horizontal Listview

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, horizontalscrollview, swiperefreshlayout

My app is currently composed by a `ViewPager` that have several `Fragments`. In a specific `Fragment` I have a `SwipeRefreshLayout` with a `ScrollView` and into this container, a HorizotalListView of type `TwoWayView`.

The problem is when i swipe horizontally in the `ListView` the vertical scroll for the `SwipeRefreshLayout`isn't disabled and sometimes it breaks the horizontal swipe during the action.

This is what I tried to do to resolve it:

```java
horizListView.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
        }

        // Handle HorizontalScrollView touch events.
        v.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }
});
```

And here is my layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_info1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
                    android:text="@string/place_proposal" />

                <org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/horizlistview"
                    android:layout_height="230dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_info2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_gray"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/actual_position"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />

                <ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/vf"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/include_w"
                        layout="@layout/include_wicard_homescreen" />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/include_no_w"
                        layout="@layout/include_no_wicard" />

                </ViewFlipper>

            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

If anyone can help me it would be great.

Comment: Try removing `v.onTouchEvent(event);` and return false instead of true

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: You should make a custom swiperefreshlayout, try this,[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989910/horizontalscrollview-inside-swiperefreshlayout)

Answer (score 1):

Override SwipeRefreshLayout. And here is my code, it works fine:

```
public class RefreshLayoutExIntercepter extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

public RefreshLayoutExIntercepter(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx);
    mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(ctx).getScaledTouchSlop();
}

public RefreshLayoutExIntercepter(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(ctx, attrs);
    mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(ctx).getScaledTouchSlop();
}

private int mTouchSlop;
private float mPrevX;

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mPrevX = event.getX();
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        final float eventX = event.getX();
        float xDiff = Math.abs(eventX - mPrevX);

        if (xDiff > mTouchSlop) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with SwipeRefreshLayout intercepting touch events. In latest support library (i am using 25.3.1 atm) this can be dealt with without extending SwipeRefreshLayout. Here's how i did it:

1. Your view that should receive touch event **must** return true in `isNestedScrollingEnabled()`.
2. Your touch listener **must** return true in `onTouchEvent()` for ACTION_DOWN events. Otherwise the events with this pointer id will be handled by SwipeRefreshLayout.
3. Your touch listener **must** return true in `onTouchEvent()` for all the actions you want to handle with your view.
4. Use `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(bool)` to turn off/on touch sensivity of SwipeRefreshLayout and its parents if any.

In OP's case setting `RecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);` should solve the issue.

Here's a sample of my custom view's code. When Using this view, i can change tabs by swiping horizontally and enjoy the functionality of SwipeRefreshLayout when the view is scrolled all the way up. All other vertical scrolling is consumed by this view. I hope it helps.

```
public void CustomScrollableView extends View {
private final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mGestureListener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        // Check if view is zoomed.
        if (mIsZooming)
            return true;

        if (Math.abs(distanceY) < Math.abs(distanceX)) return false; // horizontal scrolling

        // Calculate the new origin after scroll.
        mYOffset -= distanceY;
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(CustomScrollableView.this);
        return mYOffset < 0;
    }
}

private void blockParentScrolling(final boolean block) {
    final ViewParent parent = getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(block);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean consumedByGestureDetector = mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    blockParentScrolling(consumedByGestureDetector);
    return consumedByGestureDetector;
}

@Override
public boolean isNestedScrollingEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```