# Android SwipeRefreshLayout how to implement canChildScrollUp if child is not a ListView or ScrollView

Tags: android

Hi i have a SwipeRefreshLayout that contains a relative layout which contains a scroll view and another view currently when i scroll down the list sometimes wont scroll back up instead it runs the onRefresh function. How do i prevent it from running this unless the view is at the top? i had read about canChildScrollUp but not found a way to implement it correctly.

heres my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        >

<ScrollView 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:background="@drawable/homepage_image_1">        

             <com.alldaypa.alldaypa.customviews.CircularImageView

                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                app:border_color="#FFFFFF"
                app:border_width="8dp"
                app:shadow="false"
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/homepage_noimage_male"
                android:clickable="true"  />

           <ImageView 
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profile_image"
               android:layout_alignRight="@+id/profile_image"
               android:src="@drawable/homepage_profile_add"
               android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
               android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
           />




            <TextView android:id="@+id/profile_name"
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/company"
                android:text="Company"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/profile_name"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profile_name"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/availability"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile">        


            <TextView android:id="@+id/profile_status_title"
            android:text="Your current availability status:"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/profile_status"
            android:text="Available"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_status_title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"/>

            <TextView android:id="@+id/profile_status_reason"
            android:text="On: 01924 501370"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_status"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textColor="@color/pink"/>

        </RelativeLayout>


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/availability"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:background="@color/pink"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Messages" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/messages"
            android:background="@color/midgrey">

             <com.alldaypa.alldaypa.customviews.SwipeListView
                xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:listSelector="#00000000"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
                swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
                swipe:swipeActionLeft="reveal"
                swipe:swipeMode="left"
                swipe:swipeCloseAllItemsWhenMoveList="true"
                swipe:swipeOpenOnLongPress="false"
                swipe:swipeAnimationTime="0"
                swipe:swipeOffsetLeft="200dp"
                swipe:swipeOffsetRight="0dp"
                android:focusable="false"
            />


                <ImageView android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/searchbg"
                android:layout_below="@+id/list"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list"
                android:id="@+id/line"


                />

           <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/listitem"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="View all messages"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/viewall"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
              />

        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>



</ScrollView>

<include  layout="@layout/elv_undo_popup" android:id="@+id/undo" android:visibility="gone"/> 
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and heres where i have implemented my class

```
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.parseColor("#ed037c"), Color.parseColor("#c40053"),Color.parseColor("#ffffff"), Color.parseColor("#51af50"));

        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() { 
            @Override public void onRefresh() { 
                swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                Log.d("Swipe", "Refreshing Number"); 
                ( new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                    @Override public void run() { 

                        updateLocalData();

                    } 
                    }, 3000); 
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

thanks to @Twibit i found a way to make this work. the trick is to detect the position of the scrollview if the position is 0 make set the SwipeRefreshLayout to be enabled else disabled.

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY(); 
                if(scrollY == 0) swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
                else swipeLayout.setEnabled(false);

            }
});
```

Comment: Short version: `scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                swipeLayout.setEnabled(scrollView.getScrollY() == 0);
            }
        });`

Comment: If we replace the ScrollView above by a ListView, the solution still works in principle, but the check inside the onScrollChanged() method should be something like: listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0

Comment: nice answer! fixed my problem on the fly :)

Comment: this is awsome sir :)

Answer (score 2):

You might have to enable / disable your swipe layout if your scroll view is or isn't on top.

You can look at this link for inspiration : https://gist.github.com/Frikish/10025057

Another example that might help you : https://developer.android.com/samples/SwipeRefreshMultipleViews/src/com.example.android.swiperefreshmultipleviews/MultiSwipeRefreshLayout.html

I had another problem with horizontal scroll : [HorizontalScrollView inside SwipeRefreshLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989910/horizontalscrollview-inside-swiperefreshlayout/24453194#24453194)

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend `SwipeRefreshLayout` and overwrite the method `canChildScrollUp()` which determines whether your views can scroll up.

   ```
   //if you have several scrollable views,just iterate
   for (View view : ...) {
       if (view != null && view.isShown() && !canViewScrollUp(view)) {
           // If the view is shown, and can not scroll upwards, return false and start the 
           // gesture. 
           return false; 
       } 
   return true;
   ```
2. Iterate through your views and use the method `canViewScrollUp()` to check if any of them can not scroll up

   ```
   private static boolean canViewScrollUp(View view) {
       if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
           // For ICS and above we can call canScrollVertically() to determine this 
           return ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(view, -1);
       } else { 
           if (view instanceof AbsListView) {
           // Pre-ICS we need to manually check the first visible item and the child view's top 
           // value 
           final AbsListView listView = (AbsListView) view;
           return listView.getChildCount() > 0 &&
               (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0
                       || listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() < listView.getPaddingTop());
       } else { 
           // For all other view types we just check the getScrollY() value 
           return view.getScrollY() > 0;
       } 
   }
   ```