# SwipeRefreshLayout with nested RelativeLayout

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout, swiperefreshlayout

Hello i have the following layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

        <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector"
    android:layout_below="@+id/coupons_header" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="Header" />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

the problem is when i'm scrolling up and then down listview acts really weird view the following screen http://sger.org/image/3D0Y1b0G1m3L

how to correct attach Relative layout inside SwipeRefreshLayout

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26296897

Comment: android:clickable="true"  add this to RelativeLayout may work

Answer (score 4):

Try adding  `android:clickable="true"`  to RelativeLayout And where is `android:layout_below="@+id/coupons_header"` . Your **coupons_header** is missing. And you can also change your layout like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation ="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:weight = "1">


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:text="Header" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> It will easily work and on changing ListView content you could also change TextView text on **SwipeRefresh Listener**.