# Adding swipe-to-refresh to a list of cards

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am developing and application that will have to implement the swipe-to-refresh pattern described [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/swipe-to-refresh.html#). Looking at the android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html), it is stated that:

> You enable this behavior by adding the widget to your layout file as the parent of a `ListView` or `GridView`, and implementing the refresh behavior that gets invoked when the user swipes.

Well the issue is that I do not plan on having a `ListView` or `GridView` to layout my data, I am using cards (`android.support.design.CardView`) and I am planning on having a scrolling list of cards that the end user can swipe to refresh.

Can I still use the `SwipeToRefreshLayout` as described in the tutorial with my cards, or does it force me to use `ListView`s or `GridView`s to display my data?

Comment: will those cards you are having be in a scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) says that

> The SwipeRefreshLayout should be used whenever the user can refresh
>   the contents of a view via a vertical swipe gesture.
>   This layout should be made the parent of the view that will be
>   refreshed as a result of the gesture and can only support one direct
>   child.

It does not mention that the view must be a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView`.

Also as seen in those questions:

[SwiperefreshLayout in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236650/swiperefreshlayout-in-android)

[Android SwipeRefreshLayout how to implement canChildScrollUp if child is not a ListView or ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26295481/android-swiperefreshlayout-how-to-implement-canchildscrollup-if-child-is-not-a-l)

Both of them have implemented a `SwipeRefreshLayout` with `LinearLayout` as the child `View`. So yes it will work with the view either being a `CardView` or a `ScrollView`.

Hope it helps!!!