# Can we set distance to trigger indicator for SwipeRefreshLayout?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

SwipeRefreshLayout is so sensitive that when I swipe through the screen horizontally, with only a little bit vertical movement, the "pull to refresh" indicator will show. How can I avoid this? SwipeRefreshLayout has a function

```
public void setDistanceToTriggerSync (int distance)
```

can it has something like

```
public void setDistanceToTriggerIndicator (int distance)
```

to show the indicator only after a certain amount of vertical distance is moved downwards, or do you guys have some work around?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HorizontalScrollView inside SwipeRefreshLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989910/horizontalscrollview-inside-swiperefreshlayout)

Answer (score 3):

Hey @Viky I have faced same issue with View pager inside swipe refresh layout and I found this solution is perfect hope it help.

Following code is taken from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453194/):

> ```
> public class MySwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {
>
>     private int mTouchSlop;
>     private float mPrevX;
>     // Indicate if we've already declined the move event
>     private boolean mDeclined;
>
>     public MySwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
>         super(context, attrs);
>
>         mTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
>
>         switch (event.getAction()) {
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
>                 mPrevX = MotionEvent.obtain(event).getX();
>                 mDeclined = false; // New action
>                 break;
>
>             case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
>                 final float eventX = event.getX();
>                 float xDiff = Math.abs(eventX - mPrevX);
>
>                 if (mDeclined || xDiff > mTouchSlop) {
>                     mDeclined = true; // Memorize
>                     return false;
>                 }
>         }
>
>         return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Comment: Please mark questions as duplicate if you find the question to be the same.

Comment: @Sufian This question has a much more meaningful title (which is how/why I found it) than the older SO question. Was just wondering if marking this question as a duplicate will have any bearing on how discoverable it is?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering AFAIK marking it as a duplicate will add a link to the other (older) question. So instead of reading comments, etc, people will see it at the top of the page (that this is a dup).