# Handle dragging down on a relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have a relative layout that has a horizontal scrolling image viewer. The issue is that the parent view of this relative layout is also a SwipeToRefreshLayout so when the user scrolls down slightly it starts ac. See code:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
      android:id="@+id/item_activity_swipe_refresh_layout"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".item.ItemActivity">



      <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_activity_coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
          android:id="@+id/item_activity_app_bar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          app:elevation="0dp"
          app:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle">

          <!--  This is the view I dont want to handle Swipe to refresh/Scroll content up (Scrolling down the screen) -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/scrollable_image_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


                <!--    ....omit other code -->
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
      </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>  
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I want the above Relative layout to basically pass all other gestures besides dragging your finger down and activating the Scroll to refresh. I need that view to handle horizontal scrolling (which it does already but if the user scrolls at a slight angle downwards. It slides the image viewers slightly but also starts the swipe to refresh.

i've had a look at this https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html 
but its boggling my mind and am not sure if its even the right thing i should be looking at?

Has anyone else had to handle horizontal scrolling images or anything in a swipe to refresh layout?

Please help :(

Comment: Do you have some very special image slider? Because it typically base on horizontal `RecyclerView` and it doesn't have such problems.

Comment: I am using a viewpager. I tried to implement Recyclerview now and it still has the same issue

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989910/horizontalscrollview-inside-swiperefreshlayout) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136178/swiperefreshlayout-blocking-horizontally-scrolled-recyclerview) questions

Comment: Thank you!!! http://stackoverflow.com/a/23989911/4578531 this one fixed it for me! If you want you can set that as your answer and i will accept it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As summary from comments, RecyclerView is great for horizontal items scrolling issues. It is better, than ViewPager, because it supports recycling items. And other stuff, like animations.

To prevent `SwipeRefreshLayout` being so sensitive to vertical movement touches, you may use [such technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23989911/3379437)