# Android SwipeRefreshLayout: Pull From Left to refresh

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

How to change the SwipeRefreshLayout behavior to refresh when pulling from left instead of pulling from top?

Comment: In case of a horizontal list?

Comment: yes a horizontal recyclerview

Comment: Check out these two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136178/swiperefreshlayout-blocking-horizontally-scrolled-recyclerview, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989910/horizontalscrollview-inside-swiperefreshlayout

Comment: I don't think you understood what I'm looking for